# Why are these 2 dimmer switches connected like this and how can I rewire them with 2 traditional switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting

so I have this array of dimmer light switches.  I want to replace the middle 2 with traditional switches (well I want to replace them all, but the middle 2 are single pole switches - the outer 2 are 3 way switches).

Whats going on with the middle 2 switches? Why are there 4 wires going into the yellow screw cap?

I already tried to install traditional switches, but only 1 light would work at a time.

In new switch A, I connected the red wire and the black wire (from the wall in the yellow cap) into the terminals.  Then in switch B I connected the black wire (black cap) and the white wire (yellow cap) into the terminals and that switch would not work.  I will try again but am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Do these switches HAVE to be connected like this?

OK I have uploaded 2 more images to show all the wires coming from the wall:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice job with all the pics & the good lighting! If only _everyone_ would make such an effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the two outer wire nuts (red and black) and connect the lone red and black wires directly to the two new switches.   Leave the yellow nut and all its connected wires.  The two wires going from it to the dimmers should be cut close to the switch bodies (presuming you will be throwing those away.  Strip them and screw them to the other terminals on the two new switches.

[image]

Comment: this will work for traditional (non-dimmer) switches?

Comment: ok that did it - ill be calling an electrician to come out and inspect the wiring here too. thanks

Comment: there's actually no problem (apart from a hot white not being marked) , I thought the white wire from the wirenut went to the same /3 romex, but it actually goes to a different romex, so it's all looking good.

Comment: Actually the way that white wire is used is incorrect.  It's not a switched hot.  It's a hot, going into a /3 cable where the other two wires are switched.  Instead, the black wire in that cable should have been used as the hot, and the red and *marked* white used in the three-way switch arrangement.  If you have access to the other end of this cable, which ought to be in another switch box, you could fix this.

Comment: Also, code pedants would say you should not re-use the wires from the dimmers the way I suggest, but replace them with wires approved for use in junction boxes.  (Those wires were approved for use with those dimmers, not without them.)

Comment: This last thing was going to be my red flag. The yellow wire nut in this image should be replace with a larger red one and two pieces of #14 (white sheath, newer wiring) or #12 (white sheath, older wiring) should be pig-tailed in to connect to the new switches.

Answer (score 0):

just disconnect the original switches and connect new switches in their place.

There looked like problems with the way the wires go.

the most recent photos clear it up, the white wire is the hot for a remote end of a "3way", it's not related to the loads that theses switches operate,

still the white wire is missing a black mark that should be added to it with black tape or paint or a sharpie.

Comment: currents must balance in each raceway (here each romex) taking live from the swirtch romex and neutral from the neutral wirenut in the back of the box  violates that.

Comment: the latest photos show the switches connected to a different romes than the white, so it;s all good.